# react native realm crashed after start

Tags: react-native, realm

I just tried to get started with `react-native` and `realm`.
Followed the tutorial here: [Tutorial from realm](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#getting-started)
I did nothing, just 
- react-native init demo
- cd demo
- npm install realm --save
- react-native link

fixed the "....." stuff to "...\..."

and tried with `react-native run-android` to start the app.
It starts and closes immediately.

Why? Any ideas?

Thanks

ps: I had to install `nvm` for Windows and changed with nvm use 8.15.0 to an earlier version of node than 11.6.0.. as it seems that realm is not supporting it yet and I am testing on a real device (Xiaomi Redmi Note 5)

Comment: same for adding with yarn or using react native 0.57.1

this is the log...

--------- beginning of main
01-31 07:33:53.919  8187  8187 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
01-31 07:33:53.967  8187  8187 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
01-31 07:33:53.967  8187  8187 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
--------- beginning of crash

Answer (score 0):

It looks like v0.58.0 of react-native isn't compatible/ breaks something in realm as of now;
a temporary solution will be to initialize your RN project using v0.57.8

Steps:

```
react-native init --version="react-native@0.57.8" ProjectName
cd ProjectName
npm install realm --save or yarn add realm
react-native link
```